# How are the eigenvalues affected for a kind of similarity transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathbf{A}$ be a $N\times N$ Hermitian Matrix. Let $\mathbf{Q}$ be a $N\times N$ unitary matrix. Let $\mathbf{Q}_r$ be the matrix formed by using the first $N-1$ columns of $\mathbf{Q}$. Can we say anything about the eigenvaules of $\mathbf{Q}_r^H\mathbf{AQ}_r$? I know they are real and should be in the interval $[\lambda_{min}(\mathbf{A}),\lambda_{max}(\mathbf{A})]$.

Comment: I think you have basically said it all when you stated the range of possible values. Showing as much would be a different story<strike>, but I agree with the statement<\strike>. Though thinking about it, I think the magnitudes are confined to the same range, but could become complex if the matrices are not all real.

Comment: Hello adam, nice to see you after some time. I think the only needed condition is $\mathbf{A}$ to be hermitian, then the eigenvalues are always real for whatever $\mathbf{Q}_r$ I choose. Isn't it so?

Comment: My comment applied to your previous edit which involved a non-hermitian form. Obviously since your form is indeed hermitian it has real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $J$ be the $n \times (n-1)$ matrix consisting of the first $n-1$ column of the identity $I$. Then $Q_r = QJ$. So, denoting $Q_r^* := Q_r^H$, we see that

$$B := Q_r^* A Q = J^* Q^* A Q J,$$

which is the leading $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ principal submatrix of $Q^* A Q$. Obviously, $B$ is Hermitian, so it has real eigenvalues, and the limits you wrote apply. However, if the columns of $Q$ are not the eigenvectors of $A$, you cannot say anything more. If they are, $B$ is diagonal, and the eigenvalues are those of $A$, without the one associated with the last column of $Q$.

Notice that both of your limits are reachable, i.e., you cannot reduce $[\lambda_{\min}(A), \lambda_{\max}(A)]$ to a smaller segment without having some additional info on $Q$. To see that, simply take any unitary $Q$ such that its first two columns are the eigenvectors associated with $\lambda_{\min}(A)$ and $\lambda_{\max}(A)$, in any order.

Comment: got it !!!!!!!!!!!